# Selenium Crashing: Chrome automation extension has crashed

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I am using Selenium web drivers, and today, for no apparant reason I started getting an error with the message"Chrome Automation Extension has crashed.  Click this balloon to reload the extension".

The only thing I can think of is I added an extension for testing XPath to Chrome today.  But it was working fine for a while after I added that.

Could it be some Chrome security issue?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Add please info about which version of Selenium Webdriver you use? Also chromedrive version and chrome version.
I have the same problems.
My chromedriver is 2.23 version, selenium webdriver v 3 (beta) and chrome v.52

Answer (score 32):

I had the same problem, I could resolve it as the following:
1.Don't run Chrome as Admin.
2.Don't run your selenium App as Admin.

Comment: Thanks! This has made a trick. If you run it using console command - start console without admin rights.

Comment: How to do it if I use TeamCity to run tests? I created not admin account to start teamcity agent service but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of using Jupiter from Chrome using Spyder. It worked..

Comment: The same applies to webdriver.io. You shouldn't be running your VS Code in admin mode.

Answer (score 20):

Ok, so you are serious about the **admin** part as a *solution* to the problem?

Why not follow the *advices* from **Google**?
http://chromedriver.chromium.org/help/chrome-doesn-t-start

> Passing '--no-sandbox' flag when creating your WebDriver session.
>   Special test environments sometimes cause Chrome to crash when the
>   sandbox is enabled.

So I ended up doing as they *adviced* and can run things as **admin**.
Guess it's a way forward for me now and hopefully it's a valid solution for others too.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
browser = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, caused by running from a windows junction (mklink /D /J)

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that my Windows temp folder was on a drive (D) that is not my primary Windows drive (C) *and* that I had also mapped that drive to a sub-folder of C.

1. I went into Disk Management
2. Right-clicked my secondary drive
3. Selected "Change drive letter and paths"
4. Removed the entry where I had mounted the drive as a folder
5. Opened my Environment Settings
6. Changed my TEMP and TMP entries from "C:\Temp" (the path where my 2nd drive was mounted) to "D:\"
7. Restarted my computer

Note that step #4 was important. The plugin would still crash if this was present.

Comment: I ran into the same problem when executing Chrome from a disk which was mapped as a whole to a directory on the C:\ volume. A situation the Chrome sandbox seems to dislike. I added the --no-sandbox argument and everything worked.

Comment: I had this problem when running from a junction in windows (mklink /D /J)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but my situation is I tried to open visual studio with different profile.When i am opening visual studio with default profile its working fine.So i guess its profile issue.

Comment: When you open any solution in visual studio its uses default profile (your windows username and password).But i have to open visual studio with different profile cause of vpn connectivity issue.Now i am not able to launch chrome driver. I tried using chrome default profile but it launch the browser and return null in webdriver object.

Comment: i am facing same issue @Neeraj ..did you find any solution.?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve my problem when I start Git Bash without admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, using Python with Selenium

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path="../drivers/chromedriver.exe")
```

The above piece of code resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem. For work around we are using Firefox now. You just need to add Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver by jbaranda NuGet package

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case it was related to the Windows account I use to log in to Windows, which is account in the Administrators group. However, it was not desirable to change the account type.

To solve this I created a new local account under the control panel (of type 'power user') and used that account to run Chrome and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For Python this solved my problem use:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# start the browser
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
# options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
# options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)

#driver.quit() # Uncoment to keep chromedriver open.
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I have to run it under Admin, I fixed it by updating .NET framework. You can update this in Windows Update. I updated every item that is related to .NET framework, including crucial ones and optional ones.

Here are two items I updated:

2018-01 Preview of Quality Rollup for .NET framework (KB4057272)

.NET framework 4.7.1 (KB4033369)

Edit: I run Win 10 with chromedriver 2.34 and Chrome v64.0.3282.140(64-bit)

Comment: I don't think this answers the original posted question at all.