# Protractor Help: Admin Error Issues on a client machine

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am an automation tester that is developing tests using a laptop given to me by the client. With the client laptop there are certain security restrictions that will not allow me to add certain software, plugins, or browser extensions.  For my protractor tests, I was able to get ChromeDriver working (and run my test), but only after disabling the automation extension to bypass the security restriction.

Are there any implications of having that extension disabled and if it will affect any automation capability going forward.  Here is a similar thread on the chrome extension [Chrome extension thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164831/selenium-crashing-chrome-automation-extension-has-crashed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, I'm not using any automation extension and my tests work.

Protractor tests does not depend on any chrome extension. They work just with appropriate chrome driver.