# The process started from chrome location C:\..\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Chrome version: 68.0.3440.106 
Chrome webdriver version: ChromeDriver 2.41.578737

 
Python Version : Python 3.5.2

I write this code in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


o = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
o.add_argument("disable-extensions");
o.add_argument("--start-maximized");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe",options=o)
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

after few seconds chrome opened with this error:

[image]

 and nothing happend till i close chrome and get this exception:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../game.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe",options=o)
  File "...\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "...\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "...\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "...\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "...\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (unknown error: unable to discover open pages)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: see this post: [Selenium Crashing: Chrome automation extension has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164831/selenium-crashing-chrome-automation-extension-has-crashed)

Comment: saw, didn't helped.

Comment: you are not using correct argument, use: o.add_argument("--disable-extensions");

Answer (score 1):

use correct argument for disabling extension:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
o = Options()
#o.add_argument("--disable-extensions"); #here
o.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", false); #you can try this as well
o.add_argument("--start-maximized");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=o)
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Comment: you can try one more option: o.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false); This capability will help to not load Chrome Automation extension. I have updated my answer.

Comment: still didn't work, in python is `o.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)`

Comment: my bad, you are right. I mixed up python and java. Btw are you still getting same error?

Answer (score 1):

Today I was the same trouble and I fixed using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


o = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
o.add_argument("disable-extensions")
o.add_argument("--start-maximized")
o.binary_location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" ## This line define path of browser. In this case, Google Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe",options=o)
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Comment: Can you explain which part you changed to fix this issue?

Comment: Oliver, add this line: 
o.binary_location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" ## This line define path of browser. In this case, Google Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue using TeamCity, which was caused by chrome (and chromedriver) not shutting down after executing my script.
inserting "taskkill /f /im chrome.exe" and "taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe" fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (unknown error: unable to discover open pages)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue seems that the **chrome** binary i.e. **chrome.exe**  and the associated files are no more available/accessible from the default location of:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\
```

The possible reasons are:

- Chrome previously installed at the default location got **corrupted**/**deleted**.
- If you have installed *Chrome Browser* at a [non-standard location](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location) you [need to](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options.binary_location) do:

  ```
  opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  opt.binary_location("/path/to/other/chrome/binary");
  ```
- Here you find a detailed discussion on [Cannot find Chrome binary with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/cannot-find-chrome-binary-with-selenium-in-python-for-older-versions-of-google-c)

---

### Additional considerations

- *Chrome* and *ChromeDriver* are present in the desired location.
- *Chrome* and *ChromeDriver* are having executable permission for non-root (non-administrator) users.
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as a **non-root** user.
- Run the selenium server with `webdriver-manager start` from the machine with the desktop (don't use a remote session to start the selenium server).

Comment: The chrome was opened but after I close the window (after alot of time without any response but the error massage) I get this exception, your answer doesn't help me at all, but thanks for the try.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is here now, I had this same issue and I passed **--no-sandbox** argument and it worked. Give it a shot.

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
o = Options()
o.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=o)
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

We faced this issue using Java, Cucumber, Maven, Serenity, and IntelliJ. After trying everything the solution was so easy:

Just run IntelliJ as administrator.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33860092)