# Selenium + Python: empty output

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu-18.04

I installed selenium python for both 3 and 2.7
I run the following script:

1) vi test.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://python.org')
```

I get nothing from the output. If I remove the parameters and leave it basic:

2) vi new.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

element = driver.get('https://python.org')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.18.0-10-generic x86_64)
```

I installed:
snap install chromium
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser chromium-chromedriver
pip install selenium

Comment: Did you install Chrome browser?

Comment: @inrob try only this, `from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver");
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=stackoverflow")`. don't pass empty options also

Comment: sudo apt-get install chromium-browser chromium-chromedriver

Comment: @AliCSE Can I give you my root pass in private for this test server? I get error
 (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Comment: @inrob Already the answer is there for this question, refer [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is) or [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009351/the-process-started-from-chrome-location-c-chrome-application-chrome-exe-is) and let's see what will happen

Comment: @AliCSE, Where do i download package to be saved at .... /chrome/binary/
I am on ubuntu 18.4

Comment: @inrob For installing the chrome, refer [this link](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-google-chrome-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187563/discussion-between-ali-cse-and-inrob).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's normal do not see the driver (automated browser) during the headless mode.
2. Try to install Chrome browser (your second script):

`wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Hope it helps you!

Comment: sudo apt-get install chromium-browser chromium-chromedriver

Comment: @inrob, check, please, my updated answer.

Comment: sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
OUTPUTS:
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb': No                        such file or directory

Comment: You need to download first the .deb-package. See my updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: How is going? Did you try my last update?

Comment: Hi. this:https://pastebin.com/raw/qsxnmdkq Doesnt work.
Neither does this
https://pastebin.com/raw/Qhx10upU

but this works:
https://pastebin.com/raw/S707uKFv

Any ideas? Also are you available for consulting?

Comment: Did it fix your problem? 
Is it a virtual machine with Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, testing machine, if you want I can give login details to check. At least the last example works. I needed one working example.However when I connect with vnc it shows gray screen

Comment: So, you do not have a monitor for this machine? In this case, it will work only in headless mode (when your browser physically is not visible).

If my answer is fixed your asked above problem -- you can accept my answer (check a tick near my answer). Thanks.

Comment: I mean monitor as the physical display.

Comment: Nope, just a vultr vps is all I have. I used to do it before, the same way

Comment: @inrob, in this case, you can run only in headless mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187586/discussion-between-inrob-and-ratmir-asanov).